# Split input XML by node tag value with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have input XML which looks like:

```
<Item>
<text>String1</text>
<format/>
</Item>
<Item>
<text>String2</text>
<format>*</format>
</Item>
<Item>
<text>String3</text>
<format>*</format>
</Item>
<Item>
<text>String4</text>
<format/>
</Item>
```

And output should look like:

```
<p>String1 String2</p>
<p>String3</p>
<p>String4</p>
```

I'm new to XSLT so I don't know how to realize this with XSLT.

I've tried to loop through all first nodes of each paragraph with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Item[position()=1 or preceding-sibling::Item[1]/format='*']">

<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::Item">
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

and process following nodes untill I find "end" node with format='*' but I don't know how to define that condition in inner 'for-each'.

I guess, I'm going wrong way. Wouldn't you help me with correct XSLT code?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you can use a technique known as *sibling recursion*:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item[position()=1 or preceding-sibling::Item[1]/format='*']">
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="next-item" select="following-sibling::Item[1]" />
    <xsl:if test="not(format='*') and $next-item">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$next-item"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes a well-formed input, with a  single root element.

Comment: It works just the way I need. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use muenchien grouping like so ...

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="p-group" match="Item" use="generate-id( ((.|following-sibling::Item)[format='*'][1] | .)[last()])" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <t>
    <xsl:for-each select="t/Item[generate-id(.) = generate-id( ((.|following-sibling::Item)[format='*'][1] | .)[last()])]">
      <Item>
        <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('p-group', generate-id( ((.|following-sibling::Item)[format='*'][1] | .)[last()]))" />
        </p>
      </Item>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </t>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',text)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[not(preceding-sibling::Item[1][format != '*'])]">
  <xsl:value-of select="text" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```